Convert 2 lanes of PCIe Gen1 to one lane of Gen2
I'm wondering, is there a way to somehow combine two lanes of PCIe Gen 1 to one lane PCIe Gen 2 (link aggregation?)? Could this be achieved with a PCIe Packet Switch IC like PI7C9X2G606PR in some way? Or a redriver IC?
Edit: Clarified the labeling


Yes, the upstream and downstream links are negotiated independently.

Please clarify. In and Out are not standard PCIe terms. Please indicate upstream port (USP) and downstream port (DSP).

In means USP, OUT means DSP

Possibly, but it depends on what you are trying to accomplish.

If you are talking about having a single Gen1 x2 (*) device and a second Gen2 x1 device, then yes that will work. A PCIe switch will separate the upstream and downstream interfaces typically allowing each to negotiate it's own speed and width.

It you are talking about connecting two separate Gen1 x1 downstream devices to a single Gen2 x1 upstream port, again, a PCIe switch is the correct device for the job. The PI7C9X2G304 series is a smaller simpler device to the one you suggest that has a single Gen2 x2 USP and two Gen2 x1 DSPs.

If however you have two separate upstream Gen1x1 ports (e.g. two PCIe X1 connectors on a computer motherboard) and are trying to combine them into a single interface, this will likely not work. Aggregation of multiple ports into a single large port requires that the upstream device be capable of this, which is not a given and can be tricky to get a straight answer as to whether it is supported (most likely not).



(*) Gen1 x2 = Gen1 (2.5GTS), x2 (2 Lanes) single device link

I was looking for method mentioned in your third point. Beside that, in your point one you mentioned Gen1x2 to Gen2x1. In that case what would be the speed of the Gen2x1 device? 2,5GTS or 5GTS?

@bkausbk Sorry for the confusion, Gen2x1 means Gen2 (5GTS) x1 (1 Lane).

Thanks Tom. What I wanted to ask was if the downstream device Gen2x1 in that case (your point one) really gets the speed 2.5GTS or 5GTS.

@bkausbk yes the Gen2 port would run at 5GTS. The USP and DSP of a PCIe switch can run at different rates. The switch itself will handle receiving the packets from the narrow fast interface and feeding them out of the wider slow interface (and vice versa).

One more thing: As far as I understand that packet switch IC's also allow for example one Gen2x1 USP to three Gen2x1 DSP. In that case the bandwidth would not be sufficient. In that case, what will be the bandwidth of one of these DSP? Is this even possible?

@bkausbk They use various schemes for dividing the bandwidth, but typically in that case if only one DSP port was transferring data, it would get the full bandwidth. If two or more DSPs were trying to send data, the bandwidth would be shared between them (usually equally, but doesnt have to be). You could also have e.g. data going at full bandwidth from USP->DSP0, and simultaneously going at 1/3 bandwidth from DSP0->USP, DSP1->USP and DSP2->USP.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
